# How to I hide a SharePoint Document view based on certain variable in a Javascript code?

Tags: document-library, javascript

I have a SharePoint Document view that allow people to upload file. However, I have a Javascript variable that will control when can the people upload file.

If the javascript variable is being assigned a value, say "Close", the SharePoint Document view should either not display on the screen or the whole aspx file cannot be access.

However, if the javascript variable is being assigned a value, say "Open", the SharePoint Document view will be display and people can upload their files or click New document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the web part by making the css class for the web part as `disply="none"`

Check your javascript variable value in a function, when the value is "Close" then add the line,

```
document.getElementById(webpartid).style.display="none";
```

Here `webpartid` is the ID of the Web Part, which you can get from the source of the page, which will look something like this - `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ`

To make it back to visible you can use the code,

```
document.getElementById(webpartid).style.display="inline";
```

Comment: Took quite a while before I get everything working. I notice that most of my webpart id looks more like `WebPartWPQ?` (where question mark represent a number). Also, to know the ID, **I need to go to the client**, execute that page, find that particular key word and then use your code above).

Comment: good to know that you got it right.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, maybe you can include a note informing that one need to be at the client side (meaning that one need to open a web browser and right-click select view source code) rather than viewing the source code of the page in the SharePoint Designer.